# Why is it not possible to fill an array using an each do loop in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

If I use an each do loop to fill an array, it will leave the array as it is (in this case it will be a nil array of size 4)

```
array = Array.new(4)
array.each do |i|
  i = 5
end
```

I understand that I can initialize an array with my desired value using `array = Array.new(4) {desired value}` but there are situations in which I'm choosing between different values and I am trying to understand how the each do loop work exactly.

The current way I'm doing it is the following which fills in the array with my desired value

```
array = Array.new(4)
array.each_with_index do |val, i|
  array[i] = 5
end
```

Comment: You could alternatively pass in a second parameter to fill in the array, as such: `array = Array.new(4, 5)` which will achieve the same effect.

Comment: This is another example of someone getting confused by people insisting that Ruby is pass-by-reference. No, it isn't! It is pass-by-value. If it were pass-by-reference, the OP's code would work. I am at a loss as to why this is so controversial. Can we please just stop confusing people by claiming Ruby is pass-by-reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

You need :

```
array = Array.new(4) do |i|
  5
  # or some logic depending on i (the index between 0 and 3)
end
```

## Your code

`array = Array.new(4)`

array is now an Array with 4 elements (`nil` each time).

`array.each` iterates over those 4 elements (still `nil`), and sets `i` as block-local variable equal to `nil`.

Inside this block, you override `i` with 5, but you don't do anything with it. During the next iteration, `i` is set back to `nil`, and to `5`, and so on...

You don't change the original array, you only change local variables that have been set equal to the array elements.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that

```
i = 5
```

is an assignment. It assigns the value `5` to the variable `i`.

In Ruby, assignments only affect the local scope, they don't change the variable in the caller's scope:

```
def change(i)
  i = 5       # <- doesn't work as you might expect
end

x = nil
change(x)
x #=> nil
```

It is therefore impossible to replace an array element with another object by assigning to a variable.

On the other hand,

```
array[i] = 5
```

is not an assignment, but a disguised method invocation. It's equivalent to:

```
array.[]=(i, 5)
```

or

```
array.public_send(:[]=, i, 5)
```

It asks the array to set the element at index `i` to `5`.